Django: how to disable the HTTP_HOST check on a specific endpoint?
I defined a super simple healthcheck endpoint in my Django app (urls.py) to be used in a docker compose environment, like:
services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
    command: /start
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:5000/healthcheck/"]
      start_period: 20s
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

start.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset


python /app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.asgi --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir=/app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker

# ... various imports

def healthcheck():
    return HttpResponse()


urlpatterns = [
    # Django Admin, use {% url 'admin:index' %}
    path(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),
    # User management
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
    # Hijack
    path("hijack/", include("hijack.urls")),
    # Healthcheck
    path("healthcheck/", healthcheck, name="healthcheck"),
    # Media files
    *static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    # Static file serving when using Gunicorn + Uvicorn for local web socket development
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

In a local environment there are no issues since localhost is inside the ALLOWED_HOSTS configuration variable. But if I'm in a production environment and adding "localhost" to the allowed hosts list doesn't seem like a good practice.
Since the healthcheck endpoint is only used internally is there a way to resolve this? On the top of my head I'm thinking of something to skip this check just for that endpoint but I don't know how or if it is even possible. Maybe there are even other better solutions?

@EdoAkse not really... I would solve this adding localhost to ALLOWED_HOSTS but it doesn't seem like a good practice. I'm looking for something different here.

Just set the Host header to the suitable value when using curl. See the linked duplicate which demonstrates how to set headers while using curl.
